# Installing tarball without Make?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, make

I don't have internet access on my new Xenial VM, but I do have SFTP to a server which does. The issue is I need to install some packages. Getting them is fine, I just download them to my internet-connected server and transfer to the VM. My issue I've only seen tarballs installed with "Make". I have the Make package as a tarball, but without "Make" I don't know how to install it.

Edit: Specifically, the Tarball is `make-dfsg_4.1.orig.tar.gz`

Tl;dr - How can I install a tarball ***without*** using Make? I can do:
`$tar -xf make-dfsg_4.1.orig.tar.gz`
`$cd make-dfsg_4.1`
`$ls`
[image: Not sure where to go from here.]

Update:
The README says:

> If you need to build BNU Make and have no other 'make' progrma to use, you can use the shell script 'build.sh' instead. To do this, first run 'configure' as described in INSTALL. Then, instead of typing 'make' to build the program, type 'sh build.sh' This should compile the program in the current directory. Then you will have a Make program that you can use for './make install' or whatever else.

I don't understand what is meant by

> first run 'configure' as described in INSTALL.
>   Any insight?

Comment: If the software you are attempting to install is packaged as a tarball that you have to extract and build from source then you will need to have the tools and dependencies the developers of said software require to install it. If I understand your question correctly, you are attempting to install software from source? Do they package it as a `.deb` or as a `snap`? Please update your post with the specific tarball (what do you mean by this?) that you are having issues with.

Comment: It looks like that tarball came bundled with `make` for your convenience. Did the instructions in the `README` file mention how to install it with the bundled compiler?

Comment: Mioriin, thank you for the suggestion! Will update.

Comment: Why are you trying to install from source, instead of installing Xenial packages?

Comment: Respectfully Stephen, it would help me a lot if you could rephrase your question as a suggestion or statement. I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tarball you have is the upstream source for the Ubuntu (and Debian) `make` package. I highly recommend you install the binary package instead. You’ll find it [here for Xenial](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/make): scroll down, click on the first “Release” package which matches your architecture (probably [4.1-6 for `amd64`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/make/4.1-6)), and download [the `.deb` file](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/238573753/make_4.1-6_amd64.deb) in the “Downloadable files” section. Transfer that to your VM, and then run

```
sudo dpkg -i make_4.1-6_amd64.deb
```

from the same directory you stored it in.

`make` doesn’t have any dependencies apart from the C library, so this will work fine. For other packages, you can follow the same recipe, but you might run into `dpkg` errors caused by missing dependencies; in such circumstances you will need to find the missing packages, download them manually, transfer and install them, rinsing and repeating as necessary.

Comment: The problem is that `gmake` does not come with a boostrap procedure...you cannot compile it without having it already.

Comment: @schily yes you can, that’s the `build.sh.in` stuff.

Comment: That must be new then....

Comment: @schily 1993 at least.

Comment: Sure? IIRC, such a beast did not exist (or was not documented) 20 years ago when I created the boostrap compilation for `smake`.

Comment: @schily http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/ChangeLog.2#n5327